# Is it possible to translate keyboard/mouse inputs to controller x-input?

Tags: controllers, keyboard, mouse

With Windows 10 coming out this week, I was wondering if its possible to translate Keyboard/mouse inputs *into* emulated Xbox controller inputs? This would allow one to use a mouse and keyboard to play Xbox One games through the Windows 10 Xbox app's game-streaming.

The game-streaming feature in the Xbox app will currently only take Xbox One and Xbox 360 controller inputs for controlling the remote Xbox One, so as it stands now (and probably for the foreseeable future) you cannot control it directly through mouse and keyboard.

If there is a way to translate mouse and keyboard input into emulated Xbox controller inputs that the Windows 10 Xbox app can read, it would be a cheap alternative to expensive, hardware mouse/keyboard translators such as the XIM 4 or the ControllerMax.

---

(To be clear, I am **not** talking about the reverse -- converting xbox controller inputs into mouse and keyboard input -- which is all that my googling has been able to turn up so far...)

Comment: how could we know of any apps if it hasn't come out yet?

Comment: Windows 10 has been available for the last year or so in beta, its not that different from 8/7 in terms of compatability. I imagine this probably already exists as an option in some xbox controller emulators and there has probably already been a reason for this specifically to exist before with certain sloppy PC ports that only take controller input (Yes, those do exist)

I am not sure why my post has been downvoted.